# Count files in directories AND subdirectories? iPhone

Tags: iphone, file, count, nsfilemanager, subdirectory

I am trying to count entire files in a directory, including subdirectories. This is what I have to count files in the first folder:

```
-(NSString *)numberOfPhotos
{
    NSString *MyPath = @"/rootdirectory/"; 
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:MyPath]; 

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [directoryContent count]];
}
```

I was thinking maybe something like

```
for (file in folder){
    [file count]
{
```

but doesnt seem to work.

**UPDATE:** 
Actually, was very easy:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *subs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:musicPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *subs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:musicPath error:nil];
```

Comment: It will Return an object of NSArray not NSDirectoryEnumerator

Comment: NSArray *subs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:musicPath error:nil];

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. You need a recursive method. You pass in a directory, the method grabs all of the files in the directory, then checks each one to see if it is a directory or not. Here you'd have a for loop to check if the current object is a directory. If it is a directory, then it would call itself with the directory name. If not, it increments a counter by one and continues.

Can't post code right now, but that's the way you'd do it.

Comment: I posted some pseudo code so you can see the recursive algorithm in another answer.

Comment: +1, nitpick corner: You don't exactyly _need_ a recursive algorithm to traverse a tree, but certainly it's easier ;-)

Answer (score 1):

See if I can write code using the iPad keyboard... Using pseudo code to describe the recursive algorithm:

```
int fileCount(directory)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (file in directory)
    {
        if (isDirectory(file))
            count += fileCount(file);
        else
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```